# Ubuntu 22.04 - cups crashes at least once a day

Tags: 22.04, printing, crash

I'm running a very basic Ubuntu 22.04 setup. Every day - at least once a day - cups crashes. This has been going on since the day I installed 22.04. You don't even have to use cups. Just boot the machine, walk away, and eventually cups will crash all on its own.

Anyone have any ideas how I might fix this?

`/var/crash/_usr_sbin_cupsd.0.crash` shows this:

```
Disassembly:                                                                                     
 => 0x7f5b7a440177 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1511>: movzbl (%rcx),%eax                               
    0x7f5b7a44017a <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1514>: test   %al,%al                                   
    0x7f5b7a44017c <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1516>: setne  %dl                                       
    0x7f5b7a44017f <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1519>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi                            
    0x7f5b7a440184 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1524>: sub    $0x1,%rsi                                 
    0x7f5b7a440188 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1528>: cmp    %r12,%rsi                                 
    0x7f5b7a44018b <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1531>: jbe    0x7f5b7a43fc1e <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+142> 
    0x7f5b7a440191 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1537>: test   %dl,%dl                                   
    0x7f5b7a440193 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1539>: je     0x7f5b7a43fc1e <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+142> 
    0x7f5b7a440199 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1545>: cmp    $0x27,%al                                 
    0x7f5b7a44019b <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1547>: jg     0x7f5b7a440240 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1712>
    0x7f5b7a4401a1 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1553>: nopl   0x0(%rax)                                 
    0x7f5b7a4401a8 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1560>: cmp    $0x8,%al                                  
    0x7f5b7a4401aa <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1562>: jle    0x7f5b7a4401d0 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1600>
    0x7f5b7a4401ac <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1564>: lea    -0x9(%rax),%edx                           
    0x7f5b7a4401af <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1567>: cmp    $0x1e,%dl                                 
InstallationDate: Installed on 2023-06-13 (111 days ago)                                         
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS "Jammy Jellyfish" - Release amd64 (20230223)               
JournalErrors:                                                                                   
 Oct 03 00:00:25 dooky systemd[1]: cups.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
 Oct 03 00:00:25 dooky systemd[1]: cups.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

... and ...

```
SegvAnalysis:                                                                             
 Segfault happened at: 0x7f5b7a440177 <_cups_safe_vsnprintf+1511>:      movzbl (%rcx),%eax
 PC (0x7f5b7a440177) ok                                                                   
 source "(%rcx)" (0x00000021) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)! 
 destination "%eax" ok                                                                    
 Stack memory exhausted (SP below stack segment)                                          
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA                                                              
SourcePackage: cups                                                                       
Stacktrace:                                                                               
 #0  0x00007f5b7a440177 in _cups_safe_vsnprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2
 No symbol table info available.                                                          
 #1  0x0000560d70b34532 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bug LP 1965112](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1965112) has the same issue "SegvReason: reading NULL VMA" and has a fix released. You need version `cups (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu3)` for this. Please check the version you have installed with `cups --version`. If you have that please file a new bugreport.

Comment: I have `cups (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.7)`